# Displaying results within while loop mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables.

Main Category

Sub Category

Table Main Category contains unique ids of category items.
Table Sub Category contains sub category items which is associated with Main Category items.

A main category item can have one or more sub category items under them. I am trying to display
all main category item names and under them their associated sub category item names. But I am having problem in doing that. Here is my code :

```
$main_cat = $db->query("SELECT * FROM main_category");
while($row = $main_cat->fetch_object()){



$main_cat_id = $row->id;
$main_cat_name = $row->name;

$sub_cat = $db->query("SELECT * FROM sub_category WHERE main_cat_id=$main_cat_id");
while($row_subcat = $sub_cat->fetch_object()){

$sub_cat_name = $row_subcat->sub_name;

$div_sub .= '<table>
            <th>'.$sub_cat_name.'</th>
            </table>';

}

$div_main = '<div id="'.$main_cat_id.'">
            <h2>'.$main_cat_name.'</h2>
            '.$div_sub.'
            </div>';        

    echo $div_main;


}
```

It is displaying the 1st `div_main` in the correct way with sub items but from the second one onwards, it's displaying the current sub items as well as the previous ones. I am new to PHP, so can anyone help me out here a bit?

And if possible then how can I do this without using 2 while loops and using a JOIN only.?

Thanks

Comment: Before second while loop empty previous values `$div_sub = '';`

Comment: SELECT * FROM sub_category s join main_category m WHERE s.main_cat_id = m.main_cat_id

Answer (score 1):

You're concatenating $div_sub without resetting it for the next category, so the data just keeps adding up to your output and it keeps repeating. Basically have this to make sure it starts fresh each time (I just added the $div_sub = ''; inside the main category loop)

```
$main_cat_id = $row->id;
$main_cat_name = $row->name;
$div_sub = '';
```

For doing this with one query you can do this:

```
$main_cat = $db->query("SELECT * FROM sub_category s INNER JOIN main_category m ON (s.main_cat_id = m.id)");
```

And store it in a 2-D array (main_category => sub_categories), use this to output the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible.
Use:

```
SELECT * FROM sub_category s join main_category m on m.id = s.main_cat_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the join query

```
select * from main_category mc,sub_category  sc where sc.main_cat_id=mc.cat_id
```

from this reults you disply through loop